# integrate.odeint pausing (perhaps near removable discontinuity?)

Tags: python, scipy

I have a system of equations that I am trying to integrate with `integrate.odeint`.

Within that system are terms like `XiXj[i,j]*XiXj[j,k]/X[j]`.  It is possible for the denominator to be zero (particularly in the initial condition).  However, both terms in the numerator should go to zero there, and the whole term should be interpreted as zero (and values going into the equations are nonnegative).

What I have done to handle this is to replace  the `1/X[j]` with `Xinv[j]` which is set to be `1/X[j]` when `X[j]>eps` for some smallish `eps`, and use `1` if it is smaller than `eps`.

However, when I integrate, I find that `odeint` will sit for a very long time calculating derivatives at what appears to be a single value of `t`.  I think this is because of it trying to calculate things near a discontinuity in what I've done.

Larger values of `eps` or assigning a minimum step size reduces the probability of encountering this issue, but it can still happen.

I'm hoping to figure out how to prevent this from happening.  Unfortunately, I haven't been able to force this to happen in a simple example.  So I've stripped down my example as far as I can.

Some background on what's being solved: I'm thinking about nodes in a networkx network (so running this code will require networkx).  Nodes are susceptible, infected or recovered.  I have equations for the derivatives of the susceptible (X) and infected (Y) states of each node.  As correlations form across edges, I am also tracking the probability each edge is between S and I (XY) or S and S (XX) nodes.

Here's a system of equations.  I've set g_{ij} to be 1 and gamma_i is simply gamma in the code below.
[image]

It should be possible to just copy and paste the code and it will run it.  As it runs, the derivative function outputs the time and some simple measure of the derivatives.  You'll notice that it pauses for a long time at particular times.  Sometimes it starts up again.  Sometimes I give up waiting.

(note, the network it solves for is random, so if by some unlikely chance you don't see the behavior, run it again.  You may want to pickle the graph and reuse a graph to make things consistent between tests.)

```
from scipy import integrate
import scipy
import networkx as nx


def _dSIR_pair_based_(V, t, G, nodelist, index_of_node, tau, gamma):
    #V is a vector of states
    #t is time
    #G is a networkx Graph
    #nodelist is a list of nodes in G
    #index_of_node is a dict index_of_node[u] is i such that nodelist[i]=u
    #    {u:i for i, u in enumerate(nodelist)}
    #tau is transmission rate
    #gamma is recovery rate

    N=G.order()
    X = V[0:N] #probability node is susceptible
    eps = 0.1**(5)
    Xinv = scipy.array([1/v if v>eps else 1 for v in X]) #there are places where we divide by X[i] which may == 0.
                                                         #In those cases the numerator is (very) 0, so it's easier
                                                         #to set this up as mult by inverse with a dummy value when
                                                         #it is 1/0.
    Y = V[N:2*N] #prob node is infected
    Yinv = scipy.array([1/v if v>eps else 1 for v in Y])

    XY = V[2*N: 2*N+N**2]  #prob edge exists and is from susceptible to infected 
    XX = V[2*N+N**2:]      #prob edge exists and is between two susceptibles.

    #print X.shape, Y.shape, XY.shape, XX.shape, N
    XY.shape = (N,N)   #get them into the right shape
    XX.shape = (N,N)


    YX = XY.T #not really needed, but helps keep consistent with equations as written in text

    dX = scipy.zeros(N)
    dY = scipy.zeros(N)
    dXY = scipy.zeros((N,N))
    dXX = scipy.zeros((N,N))


    #I could make the below more efficient, but I think this sequence of for loops is easier to read, or at least understand.
    #I expect it to run quickly regardless.  Will avoid (premature) optimization for now.
    for u in nodelist:
        i = index_of_node[u]
        dY[i] += -gamma*Y[i] 
        for v in G.neighbors(u):
            j = index_of_node[v]
            dX[i] += -tau*XY[i,j]
            dY[i] += tau*XY[i,j]

            dXY[i,j] +=  - (tau+gamma)*XY[i,j] 

            for w in G.neighbors(u):
                if w == v: #skip these
                    continue
                #so w != v.  
                k= index_of_node[w]
                dXY[i,j] += tau * XX[i,j] * XY[j,k]*Xinv[j]  -  tau * YX[k,i] * XY[i,j]*Xinv[i]
                dXX[i,j] += -tau * XX[i,j] * XY[j,k]*Xinv[j] -  tau * YX[k,i] * XX[i,j]*Xinv[i]  

    dXY.shape = (N**2,1)
    dXX.shape = (N**2,1)

    dV = scipy.concatenate((dX[:, None], dY[:,None], dXY, dXX), axis=0).T[0]
    print t, sum(dV)
    return dV





def SIR_pair_based(G, nodelist, Y0, tau, gamma, tmin = 0, tmax = 100, tcount = 1001):

    times = scipy.linspace(tmin,tmax,tcount)
    X0 = 1-Y0 #if not initially infected, then initially susceptible
    N = len(Y0)

    XY0 = X0[:,None]*Y0[None,:]
    XX0 = X0[:,None]*X0[None,:]

    XY0.shape=(N**2,1)
    XX0.shape=(N**2,1)

    V0 = scipy.concatenate((X0[:,None], Y0[:,None], XY0, XX0), axis=0).T[0]
    index_of_node = {node:i for i, node in enumerate(nodelist)}

    V = integrate.odeint(_dSIR_pair_based_, V0, times, args = (G, nodelist, index_of_node, tau, gamma))#, mxstep=10)#(times[1]-times[0])/1000)




def test_SIR_pair_based():
    G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(100,0.02)
    nodelist = G.nodes()
    Y0 = scipy.array([1 if node<10 else 0 for node in nodelist])

    SIR_pair_based(G, nodelist, Y0, 1, 0.5, tmax = 10)


test_SIR_pair_based()
```

If I plot `sum(X)`, `sum(Y)` and `1-sum(X+Y)` I get the following for a larger value of `eps=0.01` (when the random graph is such that it does get through the process - sometimes it still gets stuck):

[image]

Comment: Two notes: it might be more elegant to use `scipy.where(X>eps,1/X,1)`, and you're setting this dummy value to 1 instead of 0 (as opposed to your explanation above). Furthermore, if transposing is "not really neeed", you should avoid it. I think that will need to remap memory, which takes time.

Comment: Thanks - I knew a command like that existed, but didn't remember its name offhand.  Will update the explanation (I had changed the 0 to 1 while trying to see if that helped)

Comment: So what if this pausing is really due to some singularity in the ODE? In this case odeint might try hard to get a next step, and that might take a while. So is it possible that your system is near-critical or something, and it simply takes long to solve the ODE?

Comment: @AndrasDeak  No - the system should be really nicely behaved.  But perhaps at 0*0/0, there may be problems if the denominator is getting to zero faster than the numerator because of numerical error.  I'll add a plot of roughly what it looks like.  Nice and smooth.

Comment: If `XX`, `XY` etc live up to their name, they should go more rapidly to zero than the denominator. Is it not possible to refactor your ODE in a way that doesn't contain this singularity, for instance by scaling up with `X` somehow?

Comment: Haven't had luck with that.  `XX[i,j]` will be approximately `X[i]X[j]`.  So `XX[i,j]*XX[j,k]/X[j]` should be somewhere "between" 0^4/0 and 0^2/0 (with liberal abuse of notation) as `X[j]` goes to zero.  But if there's a little bit of numerical error, it's conceivable that `X[j]` goes to zero when it should be very small, while the `XX`s aren't yet 0.  If it hits a place really near such an error, then maybe it really struggles to choose a step size.

Comment: Is there by any chance a clearly written version of the ODE?:) The instability of this formulation is bugging me, and I'm really curious about the paper-based optimization.

Comment: @AndrasDeak adding the equations to the question in .png form.

Comment: Thank you. So here's my concern: if these are really averages and covariances, then nothing forbids `<X_i Y_j>` to be nonzero while `<X_i>` is zero. You could have two correlated random variables with zero mean, for instance if `Y_j=X_i` with zero mean. Of course this only matters if the notation truly corresponds to means and covariances. But the fact that the `X`/`Y` and `XX`/`XY`-type variables are independent in the ODE, suggests that this can indeed happen (and not only due to numerical error). What do you think?

Comment: @AndrasDeak So these are (approximations to) average probabilities: <Xi> represents the average probability that node i is in a given state S.  <XiXj> represents the average probability that in the ij edge the nodes are both in state S.  I can prove (with liberal use of integrating factors) that starting from these equations all of these variables remain positive and that <XiXj> is at most <Xi> as expected in the unapproximated variables.    So it will only happen due to numerical error that one crosses 0.  Some of these are decaying exponentially, so with a tiny error it could well happen.

Comment: I've gotten it to tell me that it switches to bdf immediately before getting stuck.  I can't see how to disable the switch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122371/discussion-between-andras-deak-and-joel).